# Should the socket be closed or left open

Tags: sockets

After creating the socket to an application, I first have to authenticate before being able to read or write.
My question is if it is safe to keep the socket open or should I close the socket after  each operation?

Ben

Comment: It depends on the application and the used protocol. Can you tell more about the application?

Comment: I am working on a C++ client for BaseX (Open Source XML-database). I have already completed work on a R-client (RBaseX, available at CRAN). In that R-client, the socket is only closed when the client script is completed. This means that I only have to authenticate once. In most / a lot of the C++ examples I found for reading from and writing to a socket, the socket is closed after each operation. Authentication gives a lot of overhead but is probably or maybe safer. What are the pro's and cons of closing the socket after each operation?